# Why openssl is giving different random numbers even if the seed provided is the same?

Tags: c, random, openssl

I was writing a random number generator using openssl Random number generator apis. I am providing a seed to the random number generator. The seed is provided to the openssl using the `RAND_seed()` api of openSSL, and after giving the seed I am calling `Rand_bytes()` api to get the random number.

But the problem is, if the seed is same, Rand_bytes should give me the same random number, But in my case I' m not getting the same random number. What is the reason for this behavior ? What is the solution ?
The code is given below

```
#define _64BIT_SIZE 8

int GenerateRandom_64(unsigned char * apcRandom_64)
{
    unsigned char cRandBytes_64[_64BIT_SIZE] = {0},
                  cSeed_64[_64BIT_SIZE]      = 
                                   {0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07};
    RAND_seed(cSeed_64, _64BIT_SIZE); /* seed  is cSeed_64 */
    if(!RAND_bytes(apcRandom_64, _64BIT_SIZE))
        printf("nOt seeded the random bit generator properly\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For security purposes...

Answer (score 0):

`RAND_seed()` is the same as calling `RAND_add()` where the entropy argument takes the same value as the number of bytes in your seed buffer. `RAND_add()` mixes the seed data into the entropy pool. On systems that have `/dev/urandom`, the entropy pool gets pre-seeded from that.

Thus, `RAND_bytes()` will always produce an unpredictable sequence, unless you are running on a machine that does not provide `/dev/urandom`.

More information can be found in the [`RAND_add()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/RAND_event.html) man page.